# When you cut a projective planes you get a cylinder?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I´m not sure about that, but using fundamental polygons, is it this right?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Your first diagram is a torus, not a projective plane. If you cut a torus, you do get a cylinder.

Comment: Yes... truly! I mistaken!   :)              And both are orientable, and with Euler characteristic zero, so are homeomorphic?

Comment: The cylinder has boundary.

Comment: What are both orientable? Projective planes are not orientable...

Comment: I comment the torus and the cylinder